# ML or Time Series Models when we have multiple variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I have been working on Time Series (forecasting) models in python. I haven't managed to create an ARIMA model (with statsmodels) for multi-variables. Firstly, I am assuming this is possible!? I have managed though to create a set of ML models for multi-variables.

My question is: Are ML models generally better than ARIMA/other time series models, when we are dealing with multi-variables?

I would appreciate any comments or references comparing the two.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this question please explain why? Is this question too broad?

Comment: You generally run regression on ARIMA errors if you have independent variables or use ARIMAX (notice the X, which is for independent variables) which integrates the regression on the ARIMA model.

Comment: So if some of our variables depend on each other, then it would just not make sense to use ARIMA/ARIMAX at all?

Comment: You can remove the dependency by running PCA or use regression techniques that are robust to multicollinearity (like ridge regression).

Comment: I see. That is very helpful, thanks.